# clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ADALiOS'

Tags: swift, ios7, cocoapods, xcode7, adal

I am creating a swift project in which I am implementing Microsoft Azure B2C sdk. To do so I am writing following line in my pod

`pod 'ADALiOS', :git => 'https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-objc', :branch => 'convergence-dev'`

and this has successfullt installed ADALiOS in my pod. After that I copied samplesUserLoginViewController and samplesUseViewController views in my code. After that I copied ADAL_iPad_Storyboard.storyboard and ADAL_iPhone_Storyboard.storyboard in to project too.

Code inside my bridging header file is

    `#import "NSDictionary+UrlEncoding.h"
    #import "samplesUserLoginViewController.h"
    #import "samplesUseViewController.h"`

After all this I build my project and got below error
**clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ADALiOS'**

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: What was the actual command that produced the error?  (...from the details in the Report Navigator.)

Comment: Xcode project build command

Comment: When you tell Xcode to "build" it does a bunch of different things and lists them in the Report Navigator window.  You can see them there and expand each one for extra detail.  You need to find out which step is failing and why.

Comment: It is not recognizing ADALiOS framework there is no more info available.

Comment: solved it by removing pod and adding ADALiOS folder manually. They say the pod is not working fine with  xcode7.2 version